# How to reload a page after a transition in Streoids.js?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, mobile

I am trying to make an application using Appgyver Steroids that has a central menu (**index.html**) and other pages. My problem is that whenever I update cookie information on another page (ex. logging in), the menu does not change with the new data when I come back to the menu page by calling

```
steroids.layers.popAll().
```

When I manually call:

```
document.location.reload();
```

the page refresh takes care of this, but I can't find a way to trigger this automatically.

I've tried to use the **visibilitychange** event that Steroids.js provides, but it only works on iOS and I need it to be Android compatible.

Does anyone know what should I do to refresh the menu page every time I get back to it?
For the record I also use Angular.js on this project.

Thanks! 
Btw, this is my first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have almost no experience with "Appgyver Steroids", but I've digged a little inside Appgyver forums and here's what I've found: [preload() causes Webview variable unusable.](https://moot.it/appgyver#!/steroids#preload-causes-webview-va)

They suggest using postMessage API to comunicate between WebViews, so technically you could listen for a certain message in order to perform your reload or whatever.

*More resources:*

- [usage example (last paragraph)](http://academy.appgyver.com/courses/4/lessons/44)
- developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Hope it helps.